# building kernel with non-retpoline compiler

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

I am trying to build rtl wifi driver on ubuntu and when I `make` it gives me this message

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-50-generic/build M=/home/nane/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:245: *** You are building kernel with non-retpoline compiler, please update your compiler..  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic'
Makefile:58: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: i wish this solution help you:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145943/building-kernel-with-non-retpoline-compiler

Answer (score 0):

I searched and couldn't find a solution. The 'sudo make' option didn't work for me either. If you are experiencing this issue with the rtl wireless driver, what actually worked for me was to use the older version (5.2.4.1, not 5.2.4.4) from https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.1_22719_COEX20170518-4444.20170613 with the install.sh file from [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2394372&p=13776258#post13776258) (just renamed the folder with extracted the package's files to 'driver', did 'sudo su', and ran the install script).